# How to set a default column value when shifting Hive data to DynamoDB

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to set a default range key value when copying HDFS data to Dynamo. So far I have this which does a straight mapping where the input is 3 columns and the DB is 3 columns:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hdfs_table (a_col string, b_col string, c_col string)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 LOCATION "hdfs:///blahblah";

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_table (c1 string, c2 string, c3 string)
 STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
 TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "output_table",
                "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "c1:id,c2:timestamp,c3:data");

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dynamodb_table SELECT * FROM hdfs_table;
```

I set up a new output table with a range key which is basically a fourth column. I'd like to set the range key to a value which is passed as a parameter to this script. I suppose I'd like to do something akin to an `SQL ALTER` and `SET DEFAULT`. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if hive supports SQL type Alter and Set Default commands! you may try an indirect way by inserting a new column along with your columns of the hdfs_table. For instance,

```
INSERT into TABLE new_table SELECT hdfs_table.a_col, hdfs_table.b_col, hdfs_table.c_col, 
case when([your condition]) then [set your default value] end as d_col
FROM hdfs_table
```